# Laravel Phpunit and Dusk with CircleCI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, circleci, laravel-dusk

Has anybody been able to get [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) working on [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/).

I can get my build working and tested with PHPUnit but it fails for Laravel Dusk.

I have a base Laravel installation with Dusk installed. When I get to the `php artisan dusk` command, I get the following error.

**Error**

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Did not see expected text [Laravel] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

So it is starting the chromebrowser, but isn't hitting the site.

I have tried running with Dusk's chromedriver-linux, circleci's chromedriver, not using php serve and quite the variety of other tweaks. So far, I haven't had any luck.

Here is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/whoacowboy/dusk) and the relevant files are posted below.

**Here is my `circle.yml` file.**

```
machine:
  hosts:
    dusk.dev: 127.0.0.1
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles
  services:
    - mysql
  environment:
      APP_ENV: testing
      APP_KEY: randomq2VjceHV2t1Usdskeksa9yUI6a
  post:
    - chromedriver:
        background: true
dependencies:
  override:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
  post:
    - mv .env.example .env

test:
  override:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit
#    - ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux:
#          background: true
    - sudo php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=80:
          background: true
    - php artisan dusk
```

**`.env.example`** that I copy to `.env`

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:BaGXvpvUWnUbGA1RiOapw45K2UCK8AeYM3o62IDV9Qw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

**Screenshot** (pulled from circleci and not very helpful).

[image]

I found these articles which were helpful, but they did not work for me.

- [Running Dusk tests on Travis CI and
  CircleCI](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-dusk-continuous-integration)
- [Testing with Laravel Dusk +
  CircleCI](https://medium.com/@helovamut/testing-with-laravel-dusk-circleci-c36277210eb3)

Comment: try to add php version to your circle.yml file `php : version: 5.6.5` after your timezone

Comment: @AmrAly Thanks for the suggestion but it has the same error.

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but try changing `dusk.dev: 127.0.0.1` to either `dusk.dev: localhost` or `dusk.dev: 0.0.0.0`

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code working for us. Try this

**circle.yml** file.

```
machine:
      pre:
        - sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
        - sudo apt-get update
        - sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
      services:
        - mysql
    dependencies:
      override:
        - composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
      post:
        - mv .env.testing .env
    test:
      override:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit
        - ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux:
              background: true
        - php artisan serve:
              background: true
        - php artisan dusk
```

**.env.testing**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:BaGXvpvUWnUbGA1RiOapw45K2UCK8AeYM3o62IDV9Qw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Output [Checkout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTAj8.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The I had `sudo php artisan serve` and I needed to remove the `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the configuration that finally worked for me.

**circle.yml**

```
machine:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; USE_PRECOMPILE=true sudo -E circleci-install php 7.0.4
  php:
    version: 7.0.4
  services:
    - mysql
  post:
    - chromedriver:
        background: true

dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo composer self-update
  post:
    - cp .env.dusk.testing .env
    - php artisan serve:
        background: true

general:
  artifacts:
    - "tests/Browser/screenshots"
    - "tests/Browser/console"

test:
  override:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit
    - php artisan dusk
```

**.env.dusk.testing**

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=base64:Secr3tSecr3tSecr3tSecr3tSecr3tSecr3tSecr3tSe
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL="http://localhost:8000"
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=circle_test
DB_USERNAME=ubuntu
DB_PASSWORD=
MAIL_DRIVER=log

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```